# Issue with position:sticky footer containing buttons

Tags: javascript, css, sticky, sticky-footer

I have a floating div at the bottom of my page which consists of two buttons. To make the floating button persist at the footer, I used `position:sticky`

The issue I am facing is that when the button floats over other buttons in the page, any click on the buttons in the footer itself is disregarded and rather the click on the underlying buttons is recorded. The footer's buttons' click action is being disregarded.

I tried to deregister the click event when the buttons are out of view, taking into consideration the height of the floating footer, but even that doesn't work. Is there a way to tackle this issue?

Comment: Could you add a quick demo so we can more easily assist?

Comment: I'll try to add screenshots here

Comment: If you could set up a snippet on here (or a demo on CodeSandbox, stackblitz, CodePen, or other site), that would be best. Just note, if you go off site for the demo, you need to include the relevant parts of the code on here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because position sticky not actually put the footer button on top of the other when they overlap. To achieve what you want, simply put z-index to the sticky button (or your footer in this case)

```
.sticky-button {
 position: sticky;
 z-index: 1000;
}
```

This will make the sticky button overlay the content, and when you click, the function in the sticky button should be trigger

Comment: I did try this but it didn't work. I even set the z-index of the underlying buttons to a smaller value but that doesn't work.

Comment: did you make sure that the z-index that you set is not overridden by any other code. You can have a quick check in chrome dev tool by hovering them and see if their z-index in styles are correct

Comment: Yes that helped! I added ```!important``` after the z-index and the issue went away. Thanks a lot!